# XSLT Explicit Node selection returning nothing

Tags: xslt

I'm having trouble getting XSLT to return just the category values from the XML.  Why is lastupdate and path being returned?  ...and how can I stop this?   Thanks in advance.

XML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<categories count="3">
    <lastupdate>08/12/2010 12:27</lastupdate>
    <path>C:\</path>
    <category>Music</category>
    <category>News</category>
    <category>Sport</category>
</categories>
```

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="categories">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="category">
        <a>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>08/12/2010 12:27C:\
                        <a>Music</a>
                        <a>News</a>
                        <a>Sport</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your output suggests that this is not the full xslt your're running. I suspect there's something more in your xslt which copies `lastupdate` and `path` to your output.

Comment: I agree. Where does the table come from? It's not clear from your posted code

Comment: Judging from the indentation in his sample, he left out the table between the body and the apply-templates, which would also explain the output.

Comment: I've added the full XSLT document, cut it down to make the question more readable, had the opposite effect.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are applying template for all `categories`' child element nodes. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule

Thus you need the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="categories">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="category"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="category">
        <a>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To get desired ouput:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a>Music</a>
        <a>News</a>
        <a>Sport</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why is lastupdate and path being
>   returned?

Because [built-in rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule), precisely these two:

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Empty `apply-templates` is the same as having `select="node()"`. Then, `lastupdate` and `path` elements  get matched by built-in rule for elements (just apply templates to children nodes), and their text nodes children get matched by built-in rule for text nodes (output string value).

> ...and how can I stop this?

Overwrite one of the built in rules like:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Meaning no text node output. Or use a push style approach like

```
<xsl:template match="categories">
 <html>
  <body>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="category"/>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your <xsl:apply-templates/> applies all matching templates to all subnodes.

Because you haven't defined matching templates for lastupdate and path, XSLT applies it's default templates, which in this case copy the text content.

If you want to disable this, you either have to override the default template(s) (normally not so good) or to restrict your template application on the nodes you want to process. In your example expand the apply-templates to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="./category"/>
```

Comment: You wrote *override the default template(s) (normally not so good)*. This is wrong: mostly every transformation overwrite some built-in rule... Also, starting `./` step is verbose and not needed.

Comment: @Alejandro: A normal template overrides a general (default) rule with a specific rule that applies only to a certain subset of nodes. That is perfectly OK. To replace the default rule with a rule that applies to the same scope is in my experience almost never necessary. I included the "./" to indicate that it is an xpath-statement, since the OP didn't seem very experienced in XSLT. He might need that hint if is original case is more complicated than his sample :-)

Comment: Indentity rule (very often used) overwrites attributes built-in rule.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have something like this somewhere at the bottom of your xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This would explain why you end up with these values somewhere in the middle ouf your output.

Comment: XSLT defines default templates for nodes, attributes and text nodes, which kick in here through the general <xsl:apply-templates/> call. They are always there until overridden. If you apply the XSLT in his sample to the XML you will get the described output (apart from the missing table tags)